# Django trying to add an existing field when making a model managed

Tags: python, django

How can I stop Django 2.2.4 from trying to create a database column that already exists when making a model managed?

I have 2 models, ticket and message, which were connected to tables in a third-party database so the models were created with `managed=False`. I'm moving away from the third-party tool. The ticket model was change to `managed=True` a while ago by somebody else, and now I'm trying to do the same with the message model.

These are the relevant parts of the model:

```py
from django.db import models

class Message(models.Model):
    mid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='MID', primary_key=True)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey('Ticket', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='TID')
    author = models.CharField(db_column='AUTHOR', max_length=32)
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE')
    internal = models.CharField(db_column='INTERNAL', max_length=1)
    isoper = models.CharField(db_column='ISOPER', max_length=1)
    headers = models.TextField(db_column='HEADERS')
    msg = models.TextField(db_column='MSG')

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'messages'
        permissions = (
            ("can_change_own_worked_time", "Can change own worked time"),
            ("can_change_own_recently_worked_time", "Can change own recently worked time"),
            ("can_change_subordinate_worked_time", "Can change subordinate worked time"),
        )
```

This are the migrations that get generated by commenting out `managed=False`:

```py
# Generated by Django 2.2.4 on 2020-06-18 20:56 (0017_auto_20200618_1656)

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('troubleticket', '0016_auto_20200511_1644'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='message',
            options={'permissions': (('can_change_own_worked_time', 'Can change own worked time'), ('can_change_own_recently_worked_time', 'Can change own recently worked time'), ('can_change_subordinate_worked_time', 'Can change subordinate worked time'))},
        ),
    ]
```

```py
# Generated by Django 2.2.4 on 2020-06-18 21:14 (0018_message_ticket)

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('troubleticket', '0017_auto_20200618_1656'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='message',
            name='ticket',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='TID', default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='troubleticket.Ticket'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

When I try to apply those migrations I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'TID'")
```

The initial migration didn't include the TID column and neither do any of the subsequent migrations so I understand why Django thinks it's a new column. But it isn't a new column (the model has had it since the first time it was committed to the git repo) so I also understand why MySQL is throwing an error.

This is the initial migration:

```py
# Generated by Django 2.0.8 on 2018-08-20 14:43 (0001_initial)

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Message',
            fields=[
                ('mid', models.BigAutoField(db_column='MID', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('author', models.CharField(db_column='AUTHOR', max_length=32)),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE')),
                ('internal', models.CharField(db_column='INTERNAL', max_length=1)),
                ('isoper', models.CharField(db_column='ISOPER', max_length=1)),
                ('headers', models.TextField(db_column='HEADERS')),
                ('msg', models.TextField(db_column='MSG')),
            ],
            options={
                'managed': False,
                'db_table': 'messages',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Ticket',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('accesskey', models.CharField(db_column='ACCESSKEY', max_length=64)),
                ('open', models.DateTimeField(db_column='OPEN')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(db_column='UPDATED')),
                ('closed', models.DateTimeField(db_column='CLOSED', null=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(db_column='STATUS', max_length=3)),
                ('oper', models.CharField(db_column='OPER', max_length=32)),
                ('email', models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=128)),
                ('name', models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=128)),
                ('subject', models.CharField(db_column='SUBJECT', max_length=255)),
                ('lname', models.CharField(db_column='LNAME', max_length=50)),
                ('company', models.CharField(db_column='C0', max_length=255)),
                ('type', models.CharField(db_column='C1', max_length=255)),
                ('c2', models.CharField(db_column='C2', max_length=255)),
                ('c3', models.DecimalField(db_column='C3', decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)),
                ('c4', models.CharField(db_column='C4', max_length=255)),
                ('pending', models.CharField(db_column='C5', max_length=255)),
                ('c6', models.CharField(db_column='C6', max_length=255)),
                ('c7', models.CharField(db_column='C7', max_length=255)),
                ('c8', models.CharField(db_column='C8', max_length=255)),
                ('cc', models.CharField(db_column='C9', max_length=255)),
                ('grp', models.CharField(db_column='GRP', max_length=10)),
                ('item', models.CharField(db_column='ITEM', max_length=255)),
            ],
            options={
                'managed': False,
                'db_table': 'tickets',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I'm experiencing the same right now, and would really appreciate a fix.

Comment: @1D0BE I ended up running 3 migration commands: first migrating to 0017, then faking the problematic 0018 migration, then continuing the migration up to the current one. Not the cleanest approach and I'd have a more complicated upgrade process now if I mad multiple live installations, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Seconds after writing my comment I figured out how to solve the problem.

When 'migrating' from another ORM to Django always consider the following aspects.
The following is my recommendation of order, but I'm still learning how to use django migrations, so keep that in mind.

#### 1. Consider which fields of the model are currently known to django

It is important to note, that the actual content of the database does not matter to django when calculating which columns to add or alter. This means that, in the initial migration of the django models, where `managed` is still `=False`, the columns are "created" and registered by django. When makemigrations calculates which columns to add, it only takes the columns mentioned in the initial migration as given. Not the actual contents of the db.

Knowing that, we can now go field for field and decide for each one according to point 2.

#### 2. Consider which fields of the model should or should not be created by django

Now, generally, when setting a Model managed=True fields will fall into 3 categories.

**2.1 The field is currently in the model definition, the database, and is also in the initial commit.**

For this case, no actions need to be taken.

**2.2 The field is currently in the model definition, the database, but is not in the initial commit.**

For this case, the field definition must be added to the original initial migration script. As such, the migrations.CreateModel call might look like this:

```
...
('field_already_present', models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)),
...
```

**2.3 The field is currently in the database, but not in the model definition or the initial commit**

If the field is not needed in the django application it can be left out.
If it is needed at some point it will have to be added to the model as well as the first initial migration. That way, django makemigrations will not attempt to create the field.

#### 3. Set managed=True

Now set managed=True and make your migrations. **Do so twice!** The first time, makemigrations will set the model to managed, then it will add fields not in the initial commit.

After this, the model can be treated same as a normally created and managed-from-the-start django model.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about editing the original migration. It never occurred to me that editing an existing migration was something you could/should do, but in my case where I only have 1 live installation (so no potential differences between different DB's) that probably would have a much cleaner solution than the one I came up with. Thanks.

Comment: If there is more than one database, one could create a seperate migration for adding the field and fake it on the Database, where the field is already present.